# Python: only print the result within a tolerance for a quadratic equation

Tags: python

```
print("input a, b and c for a quadratic equation ax^2+bx+c=0")
a = float(input("a ="))
b = float(input("b ="))
c = float(input("c ="))


D = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

if D>0: 
 s1 = (-b+D**0.5)/(2*a)
 s2 = (-b-D**0.5)/(2*a)
 print("the two solutions are: {} and {}".format(s1,s2))

elif D==0:
 s3 = (-b)/(2*a)
 print("the one solution is: {}".format(s3)) 

elif D<0:
 print("no solution")
```

This code works, but I need to make this code into a function that will only print c if the difference between a and c is within a tolerance "tol", no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Did you try to write a function in Python, from your question, just an `if` will be enough right?

Comment: what does 'the difference between a and c is within a tolerance "tol" means?

Comment: Your question is not clear. what you meant by "tol" and what is it. what is the relationship between tol quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either Python's inbuilt `abs` function or NumPy's `isclose` function.

You could add another `if` statement with the condition as `abs(a - c) < tol` or `np.isclose(a, c)`, while specifying the `atol` (absolute tolerance) or `rtol` (relative tolerance) optional parameters to the desired value.

Refer: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html